# Problem with a blocking network task

Tags: java, multithreading, network-programming

I'm new in Java so please forgive any obscene errors that I may make :)

I'm developing a program in Java that among other things it should also handle clients that will connect to a server. The server has 3 threads running, and I have created them in the following way :

```
DaemonForUI du;
DaemonForPort da;
DaemonForCheck dc;

da = new DaemonForPort(3);
dc = new DaemonForCheck(5);
du = new DaemonForUI(7);

Thread t_port = new Thread(da);
Thread t_check = new Thread(dc);
Thread t_ui = new Thread(du);

t_port.setName("v1.9--PORTd");
t_check.setName("v1.9-CHECKd");
t_ui.setName("v1.9----UId");

t_port.start();
t_check.start();
t_ui.start();
```

Each thread handles a different aspect of the complete program. The thread t_ui is responsible to accept asynchronous incoming connections from clients, process the sent data and send other data back to the client. When I remove all the commands from the previous piece of code that has to with the t_ui thread, everything runs ok which in my case means that the other threads are printing their debug messages.

If I set the t_ui thread to run too, then the whole program blocks at the "accept" of the t_ui thread.

After reading at online manuals I saw that the accepted connections should be non-blocking, therefore use something like that :

```
public ServerSocketChannel ssc = null;

ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
ssc.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
ssc.configureBlocking(false);

SocketChannel sc = ssc.accept();

if (sc == null) {
    ;
}
else {
    System.out.println("The server and client are connected!");
    System.out.println("Incoming connection from: " + sc.socket().getRemoteSocketAddress());
    in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(sc.socket().getInputStream()));
    out = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(sc.socket().getOutputStream()));
    //other magic things take place after that point...
```

The thread for t_ui is created as follows :

```
class DaemonForUI implements Runnable{
    private int cnt;
    private int rr;
    public ListenerForUI serverListener;

    public DaemonForUI(int rr){
        cnt = 0;
        this.rr = rr;
        serverListener = new ListenerForUI();
    }

    public static String getCurrentTime() {
        final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
        return (sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
    }


    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t (" + cnt + ")\t (every " + rr + " sec) @ " + getCurrentTime());
            try{
                Thread.sleep(rr * 1000);
                cnt++;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong at the creation of the socket or at the use of the thread. Do you know what is causing the problem?

Every help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you put some sort of debug statement after ssc.accept(); and tell us if it gets hit? Looking at the code it doesn't look like accept should block... please verify that it is actually blocking on accept and not some other place in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use non-blocking I/O until you know you need it. Just start a new thread for every accepted socket, as well as for the accepting threads.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved :)
I looked at your suggestions and had a closer look at the code. It was a design error since I had a function that created a while(true) loop inside the constructor of DaemonForUI (and more specifically inside ListenerForUI()). It was causing the whole program to cycle through the while statement, therefore stalling every other action.

Silly mistake I must admit... :(

Thanks for all the help everyone that answered my question.

I will consider the mentioned idea of creating a new thread for every incoming connection. The duty that has to be performed for every incoming connection is not so heavy, so I thought that  one single thread could do the job.